# Read records from firebase based on a previously saved value

Tags: json, angularjs, firebase

I took an angularjs + firebase example and modified it for an app where I can register some kids for a small cross-country race.

I'm able to register kids (participants), races, locations, clubs etc. using a basic structure:

```
FIREBASE_URL/races
FIREBASE_URL/clubs
```

and so forth. When the active race is selected, I save the `raceId` and race `json-object` and can add participants to the active race.

Example:

```
FIREBASE_URL/active_race/-JI6H9VQewd444na_CQY
FIREBASE_URL/active_race/json-object
```

What I'd like to do is to get all the participants, if any, based on `raceId`:

```
FIREBASE_URL/races/-JI6H9VQewd444na_CQY/participants
```

I tried the following

```
'use strict';

app.factory('Race', function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, User) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'races');
  var races = $firebase(ref);
  var Race = {
    all: races,
    getParticipantsInRace: function () {
      var fb = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
      fb.child('active_race/raceId').once('value', function (activeSnap) {
        races.$child('/' + activeSnap.val() + '/participants');
      });
    }
  };

return Race;
```

But I believe I'm doing it wrong. I tried to prepend `return` before `races.$child` and `fb.child` but it did not solve my problem.

I tried to hardcode the following `json-array` and this is shown on the webpage:

```
return [{name: 'Claus', born: '1967'}, {name: 'John', born: '1968'}];
```

How do I get all the participants into `$scope.participantsInRace`?

I believe I have a solution, but I'm not sure if it's wise to do it this way. But it may be that simple. Prepending `$rootScope.participantsInRace =` to put it into rootScope:

```
$rootScope.participantsInRace = races.$child('/' + activeSnap.val() + '/participants');
```

Comment: It is partially solved. The $rootScope variable participantsInRace is updated but I have to perform a refresh when I have the same page open in another browser to get the same content. I believe the reason is because $rootScope is assigned in my app.factory-controller and not in app.module.

Answer (score 0):

The code is already synchronizing all data in all races when it declares `$firebase(URL+'races');`. Additionally, you never assigned your `races.$child(...)` to anything, so it's not possible to reference that data later.

```
app.factory('Race', function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, User) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'races');
  var races = $firebase(ref);
  var Race = {
    all: races,
    getParticipantsInRace: function (raceId) {
      return races[raceId]? races[raceId].participants || {};
    }
  };
  return Race;
});
```

Keep in mind that the race data won't be available until `races.$on('loaded')` is invoked (when the data returns from the server).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input. I know a bit more about angularjs and javascript now so I did some refactoring and cleanup. Hardcoding raceId works:

```
getParticipantsInRace: function () {
  return races.$child('-JIecmbdDa4kUT2L51iS').$child('participants');
}
```

When I wrap it in a call to Firebase I can't seem to return the desired data, probably due to my somewhat limited knowledge of javascript on how to return data. Example:

```
getParticipantsInRace: function () {
  ref.child('activeRace').child('raceId').once('value', function (activeSnap) {
    return races.$child(activeSnap.val()).$child('participants');
  });
}
```

My idea is to get the raceId and then return all participants. I tried to prepend return to ref.child() but still no data was returned. So not really an answer.

Regards
Claus

Answer (score 0):

This works. I changed `$rootScope.participantsInRace` to `$scope.participantsInRace` and the following:

```
getParticipantsInRace: function () {
  if (User.signedIn()) {
    var t = [];
    var user = User.getCurrent();
    var fb = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
    fb.child(user.username).child('activeRace/raceId').once('value', function (userSnap) {
      t = races.$child(userSnap.val()).$child('participants');
    });
    return t;
  }
},
```